# List to IReadOnlyList<(decimal, decimal, decimal)>

Tags: c#, list

I have a function accepting those arguments:

```cs
public decimal[] Calculate(IReadOnlyList<(decimal High, decimal Low, decimal Close)> candles, int period)
```

but I don't remember how to call it

```cs
List<BinanceKline> list = ...
Calculate(list.Select(e => new { e.High, e.Low, e.Close }), 20);
```

It returns that error which is obvious.

> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<<anonymous type: decimal High, decimal Low, decimal Close>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<(decimal High, decimal Low, decimal Close)>'

Comment: why not create a class with three variables

Comment: @Lucifer, I don't want to. This class should be unique and work for any candle class, not only for BinanceKline.

Comment: Why don't you want to create a class?

Comment: @Amy, because imagine there are people using this method with BinanceKline, Candle, whatever class. They have different properties that are not needed. The method needs only High, Low, Close

Comment: @nop Learn how to construct a class, use inheritance

Comment: @maccettura, you don't get me. They can use this class as a library for their own classes. I don't know what classes they have for candles.

Comment: That is not a good reason not to use a class.  What does it matter if the class has other properties?  You're essentially saying you don't want to even allow polymorphism.

Comment: @Amy, it just needs those 3 values. What do I need that additional class for? The method is simple. The rest of my indicators require only `decimal[] prices`. It's not worth creating a class just for one indicator. I'm following the KISS principle.

Comment: Let me introduce one concept. the DTO. DTO are data without logic. 
A simple representation used for transpering a bunch of information between applications, layers etc.
It's a no cost, simple bag that holds a bunch of properties. And has a nice name so people will understand what the propertyies are giving them a little context. 
Readability is a not a cost.

Comment: @DragandDrop, that's true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<T>` implements `IReadOnlyList<T>`, so you can do this:

```
var list = list
    .Select(e => (e.High, e.Low, e.Close))
    .ToList();

Calculate(list, 20);
```

Note that you also need to select a tuple rather than an anonymous object.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for

```
public decimal[] Calculate(
  IReadOnlyList<(decimal High, decimal Low, decimal Close)> candles, 
  int period) {...}
```

we should provide `[IReadOnly]List` and `int` (note `.ToList()`):

```
Calculate(
  list.Select(e => (e.High, e.Low, e.Close)).ToList(), 
  20);
```

when `list.Select` is *not enough*: it's just `IEnumerable<T>`

**Edit:** You may want to *redesign `Calculate` method into

```
public decimal[] Calculate<T> (
  IEnumerable<T> data, 
  int period,
  Func<T, decimal> high,
  Func<T, decimal> low,
  Func<T, decimal> close) {

  //TODO: validation here 

  List<(decimal High, decimal Low, decimal Close)> candles = data
    .Select(item => (high(item), low(item), close(item)));

  //TODO: logic from former Calculate here
}
```

And then call it as

```
Calculate(
  list, 
  20, 
  item => item.High, 
  item => item.Low,  
  item => item.Close);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.